# g++ doesn't work well when /usr/include (ubuntu) is set as the include directory

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ubuntu-18.04

On my ubuntu18.04, I tried to compile the following code with g++.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){}
```

It can be compiled without any problem. However, wjhen the following line exist inside `.bashrc`

```sh
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

I got the compilation error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:6361,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from hoge.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

It would be nice if somebody tell me why this happens.

Comment: Headers are searched from `/usr/include` by default. What are you trying to achieve by defining that environment variable?

Comment: Just I’m curious...

Comment: @eerorika If /usr/include is default search path, the export I did does is supposed to not change any behavior. But it does, which is so confusing to me.

Comment: `/usr/include` is part of the default include path it's not all of it, setting the environment variable presumably removes all the other directories from the include path

Comment: It is one of the default directories. On my system, these are searched by default:  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include Besides that, are you sure that it isn't supposed to change any behaviour? Is that what the documentation of `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` says?